# Custom loss function including output of layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a dataset that contains 1 value of `y_true` per case. I want to build a `DNN` that outputs 3 coefficients that will later be used as follows to create `y_pred`

```
y_pred = 4*coeff_1 + 5*coeff_2 + 6 *coeff_3
```

I am using `keras` and when i tried to define a custom function like this

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import advanced_activations
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error 

import keras.backend as K

def custom_objective(layer):
    return K.sum(layer.output)

NN_model = Sequential()

# The Input Layer :
NN_model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))

# The Hidden Layers :
NN_model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='elu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='elu'))

output_layer = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear')

# The Output Layer :
NN_model.add(output_layer)

# Compile the network :
NN_model.compile(loss=custom_objective(output_layer), optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
NN_model.summary()

NN_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,verbose = 1)

print('NN train = ', mean_absolute_error(y_train , NN_model.predict(X_train)))    

predictions = NN_model.predict(X_test)

MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_test , predictions)

print('NN MAE = ', MAE)
```

I get all

> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use
>   `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,
>   and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs
>   conditioned on the value of a tensor.

So my question is

How can I define a `DNN` that will take 1 `y_true` per data, output 3 values which it will combine linearly to assemble a `y_pred` which will be used to get the loss function and train the network

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is your y_train shape?

Comment: 4071 x 1 as In 1 value for each training example

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want your network to predict that?

Comment: Yes, it is a long story, but suffice to say, these three values are calculated by three indicative analytical models and only the combination of those models is sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something along these lines?

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Add, Lambda


def model(inp_size):
    inp = Input(shape=(inp_size, 1))

    x1 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(inp)
    x1 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x1)
    x1 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x1)

    x2 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(inp)
    x2 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x2)
    x2 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x2)

    x3 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(inp)
    x3 = Dense(20, activation='elu')(x3)
    x3 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x3)

    x1 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 4.0)(x1)
    x2 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 5.0)(x2)
    x3 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 6.0)(x3)
    out = Add()([x1, x2, x3])

    return Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)
```

Comment: hello, thanks but i am at a bit of a loss, supposing i have an input np array of the size (4000, 46), how do i use the code? I am sorry if this is a noob question, i am quite new at these things

Comment: @john Great! Sorry, I was not able to reply to your earlier comment. I was not near my PC.

Comment: Not a problem. Can i ask another question though? I had the code changed a bit to fit the dimensions and now it has a very strange and annoying problem
 . Is it possible i am using the thhing wrongly?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/l3YDl
here is the file if you are still inclined to help. Thanks anyway, you have been a great help

Comment: Sure. I'll take a look.